# search for rows that each of its column will match the target range (in integer)

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, match

I have a sql table like the following

```
-----------------------------------
|id | price | A | B | C | ... | Z |
-----------------------------------
```

each column of A - Z has value b/t 0 - 99

and I would like to search for all rows that match my target value range.

eg. target (A:62, B:14, .. Z:99), find every row that its corresponding value is greater or equal to the target value.

so the query will be something like

```
select id, MAX(price) where A >= user.a AND B>=user.b And.. AND Z >= user.z
```

my question is how to optimize it.

Like will it be faster if I tear the table apart into few pieces and do a nested query? or is there some technique that I should use?

edit: I did index all my attributes column, (since updating the table is none of my businese) Moreover, I actually added 2 column, 1st is sum: sum of all columns; 2nd is max_num : maximum number of all column.  then create a view against the target base on these 2 number, then perform a search.

Thank you all in advance!

And thank you for helping me to put them in code style text!

Comment: Have you tried running the code that you have? What was the performance like? Don't fall victim to premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Create some indexes may speed up the query.

like:

```
create index i1 on t1(A);
create index i2 on t1(B);
create index i3 on t1(C);
```

Comment: Ture, index helps I guess, I should add that in my question. Moreover, I actually added 2 column, 1is  sum: sum of all columns; and max_num : maximum number of all column.  then create a view against the target base on these 2 number, then perform a search.